# Using the Facebook php SDK to retrieve photos and about info

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I was just getting into the testing of the SDK for the Facebook app development using PHP. I understand the basic set up to get started, but I'm not sure how to pull album photos so I can display them throughout my page when the user logs in. Is this documented in the development section on Facebook or is there some kind of guide i can look over?

I'm able to display names but I'd also like an array of photos from the libraries and the users' information like work. I've tried searching for specifics to get this implemented but I'm not hitting any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm not sure how to pull album photos so I can display them throughout my page when the user logs in.

Take a look at this awesome tool- [**Graph API Explorer**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Also, you should read about the [**Permissions**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/). By taking the different permissions from your user, you can fetch the related data of the user. You can test the same using the Graph API Explorer- just click on Get Access Token to set the different permissions.

For eg, if you want to fetch the user's photo, ask for the permission (while login, using `scope parameter`)- **user_photos** and simply call:

`/me/photos`

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos)

> users' information like work

permissions: **user_work_history**

call : `me/?fields=work`

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2F%3Ffields%3Dwork)